# Swift React Native Callback Modules

Tags: javascript, objective-c, swift, react-native

I'm trying to create a native swift module with a function I can call in my javascript code. Currently I have my `module.swift` file, my `module.m` file, and the bridging header.

Here's MyModule.swift:

```
import Foundation

@objc(MyModule)
class MyModule: NSObject {

  @objc func callbackMethod(callback: RCTResponseSenderBlock) -> Void {
     let resultsDict = [
     "success" : true
     ];

    callback([NSNull() ,resultsDict])
  }

}
```

Here's MyModule.m:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

// CalendarManagerBridge.m
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
#import <React/RCTEventEmitter.h>

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(MyModule, NSObject)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(callbackMethod:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback)

@end
```

Here's the bridging header:

```
#import React/RCTBridgeModule.h

#import React/RCTEventEmitter.h
```

Finally, here's my call in javascript:

```
const { MyModule } = require('NativeModules');
MyModule.callbackMethod((err,r) => console.log(r));
```

The problem is that whenever I run the project, it causes an error:

```
Exception 'callbackMethod:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback is not a recognized Objective-c
 method.'
```

However, I can't find anything wrong with the documentation. Could someone please provide some help?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a `_` before the first argument in your swift method:

```
import Foundation

@objc(MyModule)
class MyModule: NSObject {

  @objc func callbackMethod(_ callback: RCTResponseSenderBlock) -> Void {
     let resultsDict = [
     "success" : true
     ];

    callback([NSNull() ,resultsDict])
  }

}
```